# Keras: Method on_batch_end() is slow but I have no callbacks?

Tags: python, keras

Keras just warned me:

> UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (0.988304). Check your callbacks.

I have no callbacks in my keras script, but I am using `DataGenerator` (`keras.utils.Sequence`). Could this be a problem?

For the `DataGenerator`, I have implemented `__init__()`, `__len__()`, `__getitem()__`, and `on_epoch_end` methods.

For `on_epoch_end`, I have:

```
def on_epoch_end(self):
    """
    This method will be called between every epoch, so we can shuffle the
    indexes here.
    """
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.image_names))
    if self.shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

The complete callstack is as below:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   /var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_30551/anaconda/envs/cellimage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/transform/_warps.py:84: UserWarning: The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to 'reflect' in skimage 0.15.
>
> warn("The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to 'reflect' in "
>   /var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_30551/anaconda/envs/cellimage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:120: UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (0.586719). Check your callbacks.
>     % delta_t_median)
>
> /var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_30551/anaconda/envs/cellimage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:120: UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (0.988304). Check your callbacks.
>     % delta_t_median)

Comment: Do you cave custom metrics or custom losses?

Comment: From which part of keras code does this message come from? (Do you have the complete call stack?)

Comment: @DanielMöller I didn't use custom metrics or losses. I just updated the complete error call stack in the question.

Comment: `__getitem__` is called to generate each batch, it might be inside the timing for callback check. Do you do a lot of processing to generate a batch?

Comment: @nuric I think my `__getitem__` has a fair workload. For each batch, it just loads 32 local `npz` files.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 5):

This could be related to your setting for `verbose`.

I'm seeing the same the same.  I believe it's because I have `verbose=1` on the call to `fit()` - i.e. printing the progress bar and current statistics is a batch-end task which is taking a too long.  This hypothesis is supported by the evidence that the warnings stop if I set `verbose=2` which only prints on epoch end or `verbose=0` which doesn't print at all.  The warnings also stop if I increase the batch size.

Comment: changed verbose=2 got rid of the warning.. With verbose=1 also noticed data printed for the epoch is not for the final step.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning that some step of your training process (other than the batch update) is unexpectedly slow.

I get the same warning by training the same model in 2 separate instances of jupyter notebook. (But where only training 1 model at a time does not produce the warning.)

Regarding your data generator. It could be causing the problem.
If your batch size is very small, the batch update step could be much faster than the interim computations.

This github issue illustrates examples of heavy cpu load, odd training settings (like extremely small batch size), and other possible triggers for the warning
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5008